# Rail 3 routes: add restful method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Should this routes.rb code:

```
  resource :oauths do
    get :callback
  end
```

be equivalent to:

```
  match "oauth/callback" => "oauths#callback"
```

?
If I use first variant and get undefined callback when accessing oauth/callback, the second method works, is there a variant to do this using "resource"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up a [collection route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions),

```
resource :oauths do
  get :callback, :on => :collection
end
```

You'll also get the `callback_oauths_path` route helper.

Comment: Yes I too found it in the docs, but it does not work to in my case: undefined method `callback' for Sorcery::Controller::Config:Module and with match "oauth/callback" => "oauths#callback" it works